# Assigning data.frame column class from other data.frame R

Tags: r, list, class, dataframe, typeof

I have a list of data.frames `sampleList`. Each data.frame in that `list` is a bit different in terms of columns and their orders.

I also have another `data.frame` `refData1`, which I would like to use as a model for the rest in terms of class of column with the same titles.

In other words, I would like the `sampleList` to be updated and any matching columns with `refData1` should change their class and reflect the class type in `refData1` for the corresponding column. The columns that are not matching should stay as they are. Please, not that `refData1` contains also a column that none of the data.frames in the list has. Thank you.

```
sampleData1 <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
                          gender = as.factor(sample(c("Male", "Female"), 
                                                    10, replace = TRUE)),
                          age = as.character(rnorm(10, 40, 10)),
                          height = as.character(rnorm(10,170,5)))
sampleData2 <- data.frame(weight = as.character(rnorm(10,80,5)),
                          gender = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 
                                          10, replace = TRUE),
                          id = 11:20, 
                          age = rnorm(10, 44, 10))
sampleData3 <- data.frame(id = as.factor(21:30), 
                          age = as.character(rnorm(10, 36, 10)),
                          gender = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 10, 
                                          replace = TRUE),
                          score = as.character(rnorm(10,20,2)))
sampleList <- list(sampleData1,sampleData2,sampleData3)

refData1 <- data.frame(id = 1:10, # numeric
                       gender1 = as.character(sample(c("Male", "Female"), 
                                                     10, replace = TRUE)),
                       agen = rnorm(10, 40, 10), # numeric
                       height = rnorm(10,170,5), # numeric
                       weight = rnorm(10,80,5),  # numeric
                       other = as.factor(sample(c("a", "b","c"), 
                                                10, replace = TRUE)))
```

Comment: I get this error while compiling your code: "Error in as.factor(id = 21:30) : unused argument (id = 21:30)"

Comment: Apologies, i corrected this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We loop through the 'sampleList', get the `intersect`ing columns with 'refData1', set the `class` of data.frame with the ones in the 'refData1'

```
sampleListN <- lapply(sampleList, function(x) {
        nm1 <- intersect(names(x), names(refData1))
        x[nm1] <- Map(function(u, v) {class(u) <- class(v)
                               u},
                       x[nm1], refData1[nm1])
         x})
```

As @mt1022 mentioned, if we go by the logic, then `factor` columns converting directly to `integer` can create issues as we wrong values i.e. integer storage values instead of the actual values.  Based on the data, we don't even need to compare with 'refData1'.  We can do this automatically with `type.convert`

```
lapply(sampleList, function(x) {
       nm1 <- intersect(names(x), names(refData1))
       x[nm1] <- lapply(x[nm1], function(x)
             type.convert(as.character(x), as.is = TRUE))
       x})
```

Comment: Works brilliantly - thank you @akrun! One more question if I can - now how do I take the `sampleListN` and merge into one big data.frame but only for those columns that appear in `refData1`?

Comment: @MIH If it is base R, then `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = columnsofinterest), c(refData1, sampleListN))`  merging is not clear because some columns for refData1 are continuous

Comment: Be careful when converting factor to numeric types. Some times converting first to character type is needed. In this example, the id for third data.frame becomes 1:10 rather 21:30.

Comment: True @mt1022 - shall I convert all factors to character in the list, if the column name matches one in `refData1`, or can it be somehow squeezed to the neat piece of code done by @akrun?

Comment: @akrun sadly your piece of code with Reduce() does not work, get the following error:  `Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns`. I do have everything defined including `columnsofinterest`

Comment: @MIH  I meant columnsofinterest as an object defined

Comment: I did define `columnsofinterest <- colnames(refData1)`.

Comment: @MIH But not every column in refData1 is in the other dataset, right.  Perhaps you need `intersect(colnames(refData1), names(sampledata1))` etc

Comment: Do I simply proceed like this (sorry but i am not familiar with ... in functions, I typically do it old-fashioned way.
`df.merged <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = columnsofinterest), c(refData1, sampleListN))` . Thank you.

Comment: Actually, managed to do it with `plyr` library `ldply(sampleListN,data.frame)` then I will just leave the columns that I need. Many thanks @akrun!

Comment: @What you need is `out <- refData1;
 for(i in seq_along(sampleList)) out <- merge(out, sampleList[[i]], by = intersect(names(out), names(sampleList[[i]])))`  But, unfortunately, there are no irows that match based on your condition